# SQL how to select only single row using joining?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the tables:

tblClients:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | sName |
+----+-------+
| 22 | User1 |
| 23 | User2 |
+----+-------+
```

tblKeys:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | sValue|
+----+-------+
| 1  | Key1  |
| 2  | Key2  |
+----+-------+
```

tblEntries:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| ID |       datDate       | lClientID | lKeyID     |
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 22.10.2019 22:16:34 |        22 |            |
|  2 | 22.10.2019 22:16:34 |        22 |          1 |
|  3 | 22.10.2019 22:16:30 |        23 |            |
|  4 | 22.10.2019 22:16:38 |        23 |          1 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
```

lClientID and lKeyID (optional) refer to above tables.

I need a SQL query which gives me the list of the users from the tblEntries only with maximum datDate field. Now i used the follwing SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblEntries.lClientId, tblEntries.datDate, tblKeys.sValue
FROM (tblEntries INNER JOIN (SELECT lClientId, MAX(datDate) AS datLastAccess FROM tblEntries GROUP BY lClientId)  AS z1 ON (tblEntries.datDate = z1.datLastAccess) AND (tblEntries.lClientId = z1.lClientId)) LEFT JOIN tblKeys ON tblEntries.lKeyId = tblKeys.ID;
```

The problem i encountered is the datLastAccess can contains the equal values so i get the duplicates with the two different keys. I need only the single entry per lClientID. If there are two items with the same values of datDate and lClientID but with the different lKeyID i need only the last one.

Now i get:

```
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| lClientId |       datDate       | sValue |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
|        22 | 22.10.2019 22:16:34 |        |
|        22 | 22.10.2019 22:16:34 | Key1   |
|        23 | 22.10.2019 22:16:38 |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

I don't need the first row (with empty sValue)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Access, I would recommend:

```
select l.lclientId, l.datdate, k.svalue
from tblEntries e inner join
     tblKeys k
     on e.lkeyId = k.keyId
where l.id = (select top (1) l2.id
              from tblEntries l2
              where l2.lclientId = l.lclientId
              order by l2.datdate desc, l2.id desc
             );
```

Notes:

- You don't need `tblClients` for this query.
- The `where` clause is getting exactly one matching row for each entry per client, because it is comparing on the `id` column.
- There is no requirement that `id`s increase with the date -- although if that is the case, the query can be further simplified.

In addition, the subquery can take advantage of an index on `tblEnties(lclientId, datdate desc, id desc)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead of aggregation to get the row with the last `datdate` of each `lClientID`:

```
SELECT e.lClientId, e.datDate, k.sValue
FROM (
  SELECT e.* FROM tblEntries AS e 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tblEntries
    WHERE lClientId = e.lClientId
    AND ((datDate > e.datDate) OR ((datDate = e.datDate) AND ID > e.ID))
  )
) AS e 
LEFT JOIN tblKeys AS k ON e.lKeyId = k.ID;
```

Results:

```
lClientId   datDate               sValue
22          22/10/2019 22:16:34   Key1
23          22/10/2019 22:16:38   Key1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other logic but you can achieve your desired output from `TBLENTRIES` table using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function.

The Simplified version of your solution:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT T.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lClientId  ORDER BY DATDATE DESC) AS RN
  FROM TBLENTRIES AS T)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Access does not support window functions.

Comment: Oh Yes @forpas, I totally missed that.